# EF Core selected values not translated properly to SQL query

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have the LINQ query with the simple select statement which maps the columns from a table to the custom entity.

```
// ... omitted for brevity
.Select(src => new ConsolidatedPaymentTransaction
{
    AccountNumber = src.AccountNumber,
    Date = src.RowStartDate,
    TransactionIdentifier = src.TransactionIdentifier,
    EffectiveDate = null,
    PaidToDate = src.PaidToDate,
    AmountPosted = 0m,
    PrincipalAmount = 0m,
    PrincipalBalanceAfterTransaction = 0m,
    InterestAmount = 0m,
    EscrowAmount = 0m,
    EscrowBalanceAfterTransaction = 0m,
    LateChargeAmount = 0m,
    UnappliedFundsAmount = src.UnappliedFundsBucketAmount,
    UnappliedFundsBalanceAfterTransaction = src.UnappliedFundsBucketBalance,
    SequenceNumber = src.SequenceNumber
}));
```

Since I'm selecting different columns from three different tables into the common entity structure. I must keep the same amount of columns in the generated SQL query to generate the valid `UNION ALL` query. However, EF is removing those properties with hardcoded values when generating the SQL query and I keep getting the exception where I'm being warned that  selects from different tables must contain the same columns while performing a union.

This is the query being generated for this particular select statement.

```
SELECT
  l.accountnumber AS "AccountNumber",
  l.row_start_date AS "Date",
  l.transactionidentifier AS "TransactionIdentifier",
  NULL AS "EffectiveDate",
  l.paidtodate AS "PaidToDate",
  0.0 AS "AmountPosted",
  l.unappliedfundsbucketamount AS "UnappliedFundsAmount",
  l.unappliedfundsbucketbalance AS "UnappliedFundsBalanceAfterTransaction",
  l.sequencenumber AS "SequenceNumber"
FROM loanhistoryunapplied_h AS l
```

As you can see, the `EffectiveDate` and `AmountPosted` columns even got the defaults correctly, but the other default values are missing for some reason. Is there a way for me to enforce the generation of all of these values in the final SQL query? What am I missing?

**EDIT: Created the fiddle which reproduces this behavior**
https://dotnetfiddle.net/sxZVxZ

Execution of the query fails because I didn't define the table, but you can clearly see in the console log that the generated query maps only the first column with hardcoded zero.

```
SELECT [f].[Id] AS [Bar], 0 AS [Baz] -- Baz2 and Baz3 are missing
FROM [Foos] AS [f]
```

Comment: What do you need them for?  When you receive the result add to your result as many empty fields as you need.

Comment: What is `ConsolidatedPaymentTransaction`? Is it registered entity type (keyless or regular) and if yes, does it have not mapped (ignored) properties?

Comment: @Sergey As I explained in the text of the question, I need those fields generated in my selection because I'm performing a union between multiple table selections, and the union can't be done unless each table select contains the same amount and type of columns. While adding empty fields afterwards would be suitable for a single table select with some computed properties, it's not suitable for my case.

Comment: @IvanStoev `ConsolidatedPaymentTransaction` is DTO, it's not a registered entity type.

Comment: What exact EFC version are you targeting? Also does it happen with anonymous type projection, e.g. `new { ... }`?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm targeting version 5.0.2, the same thing happens with anonymous type too.

Comment: Did you try something like this  PrincipalAmount =src.UnappliedFundsBucketAmount-src.UnappliedFundsBucketAmount?

Comment: @Sergey it seemed like a great idea honestly, but it generates `l.unappliedfundsbucketamount - l.unappliedfundsbucketamount AS "PaidToDate"` once and truncates the logic for rest of the columns. It seems like there is some optimization underneath the hood making me miserable...

Comment: Try to use unappliedfundsbucketbalance  instead

Comment: @Sergey same result unfortunately...

Comment: @Sergey I added the fiddle example if you want to give it a try.

Comment: i believe this may help try it and let me know https://dotnetfiddle.net/TTzrx0
showing that for a dynamic, you may need to set the type.. aka `EffectiveDate = null,` would be come `EffectiveDate = (System.DateTime?)null` let me know if that works

Comment: @Seabizkit I tried doing that as well, it's working fine for a single property of that type, but if you have multiple properties of the same type (decimal?) for example and you set more than 1 property of that type to null or 0, only the first one with that default value gets mapped to select query.

Comment: @msmolcic i just tried what ur suggesting in the dotnetfiddle and it worked fine. aka i had multiple properties of the same type (decimal?)  and mixed

Comment: include how you doing your joins perhaps those are fishy

Comment: @Seabizkit you're right, columns do not get truncated when I do the union, it throws the error that indicates something like this. This seems to be my actual issue: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129 , some of my numeric columns are numeric(7,2), some are numeric(9,2) and some are numeric(11,2) and EF has trouble mapping those.

Comment: i see so you just need to ensure they all being set to the same size. Please add the union stuff so the full picture can be seen.

Comment: @Seabizkit the issue is, I can't alter these columns on the DB level, is there a way for me to tell the EF it's fine to map both numeric(7,2) and numeric(11,2) under same decimal property?

Comment: probably not... but you could cast it..... which would mostly be the best and work.. rather than telling ef something which isnt. again it hard to see without the complete picture.. columns and unions info missing